# Unable to get BEARER token from Salesforce

Tags: community, api, accesstoken

I am trying to get bearer key from Salesforce via postman. we have done all the connected app setting with Oauth enabling and user access.

Upon using the POST method in postman
URL like
https://endpoint/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=*********'&client_secret=*******&username=*****.com&password=******

I get the bearer key at times, same request returns to BAD request("error": "invalid_grant") most of the time

Comment: Do you have the security token appended with the password?

Comment: @JayantDas Thank you, that was the one missing